# Need help to understand better the ul tags on html5

Tags: html

I'm fairly new to the coding world, right now I'm taking a course at Udemy about web developing and I'm on the HTML5 section.

the course guide was teaching about the `ul` tags and nested lists and how to write them.
the example he was giving was looking like this :

[image: example 1]

... but when I looked up this topic on w3schools website their example was a little bit different, like this:

[image: example 2]

Both ways gave the same results, but were written in different ways.
So I was wondering, which example is the right example? Does it even matter?

Comment: Use the w3school's reference as it is good to use it

Comment: Not much difference in both except for when you will go style

Comment: https://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Could you please put actual code in the question rather than images?

Answer (score 2):

The `<ul>` and `<ol>` tags can only contain `<li>` tags.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

[image]

## Nesting

```html
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item     
  <!-- Look, the closing </li> tag is not placed here! -->
    <ul>
      <li>second item first subitem</li>
      <li>second item second subitem
      <!-- Same for the second nested unordered list! -->
        <ul>
          <li>second item second subitem first sub-subitem</li>
          <li>second item second subitem second sub-subitem</li>
          <li>second item second subitem third sub-subitem</li>
        </ul>
      </li> <!-- Closing </li> tag for the li that
                  contains the third unordered list -->
      <li>second item third subitem</li>
    </ul>
  <!-- Here is the closing </li> tag -->
  </li>
  <li>third item</li>
</ul>
```

You probably noticed that the HTML spec is very forgiven to errors, but it is good practice to follow correct semantics.

Living standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-ul-element

https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/content/#nested-lists

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` (list item) must be child of `<ul>` (unordered list) or `<ol>` (ordered list)

`<ul>` and `<ol>` must only have `<li>`s as children

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#Nesting_a_list

Answer (score 0):

A nested `ul` element should be *inside* an `li` element.

Example on w3.org: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/content/#nested-lists

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention - In the Udemy course i'm taking somebody was asking in the Q&A section of the video this question:

"I saw people create sublists start from the inside the li  tag and the way you describe here. Both are visually the same. Any technical differences are there?"

```
<ol>
<li>Item One</li>
<li>Item Two
    <ol>
        <li>Sublist Item One</li>
        <li>Sublist Item Two</li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Item Three</li>
```

the instructer answer was:
"The difference is that when you add something like an event listener to the above, the li element of ITEM TWO will contain the sublist as well. So that when you click on SUBLIST ITEM ONE, it will trigger that the ITEM TWO was clicked. Does that make sense?"

is the instructer claim correct ?